# Validate SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, c#-3.0

How i could check if i have connection to an SQL Server with the Connection String known in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Ok");
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Not Ok");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I"m not sure if you are asking how to validate a connection string or check to see if a current connection is open  If you are trying to check if a current connection is open you can use.

```
connection.State
```

[ConnectionState Enumeration Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also test it outside of your code by making an UDL file (a text file with extension .UDL). Then right-click it, get the properties and enter the connectionstring details.
Press the "Test Connection" button and then you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

Check the state of the connection.

```
if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    conexion.Open();
}
```